# JAVA EE HIBERNATE CRITERIA API : add rows in database

Tags: java, criteria

Is it possible to add rows in a MySQL database with criteria API ?

For example instead

```
session.createCriteria(User.class).list();
```

I would like to do something like this...

```
session.createCriteria(User.class).addToDatabase();
```

Is that possible ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `Criteria` API is used to do "selects" on a database with an object-oriented way. It cannot be used to insert/update elements.

For this, you may take a look to `Session` : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html

Comment: There are now `CriteriaUpdate` and `CriteriaDelete` objects to do update and delete elements. However, I didn't found anything like `CriteriaInsert`, so I guess it's not possible for now ?